# UIColor code in a variable in swift

Tags: swift, uicolor

I want to set the background color of view through a parameter so that when 1 want to change it I can change it. The value of the parameter is coming from database. My current code is like follows:

```
loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.75, blue:0.14, alpha:1.0)
```

I want to change the above code as follows:

```
loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:a, green:b, blue:c, alpha:d)

                                 or

loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex)
```

Where a, b, c, d and hex are variables and all of these have a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If hex is an Int and not a String you can use this extension:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: Int, alpha: CGFloat) {
        let red = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF)) / 255.0
        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
UIColor(0x00ff00, alpha: 1.0)
UIColor(hex, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: I've been using this extension reliably, but I just noticed that it creates a slightly different color than the color created if I set the same hex color in the storyboard. The storyboard color is slightly darker. Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 2):

```
extension String {
    subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> String {
        return substringWithRange(advance(startIndex,range.startIndex)..<advance(startIndex,range.endIndex))
    }
}
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(htmlColor:String, alpha: Double) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat( strtoul(htmlColor[0...1], nil, 16) )/255.0,
                green: CGFloat( strtoul(htmlColor[2...3], nil, 16) )/255.0,
                 blue: CGFloat( strtoul(htmlColor[4...5], nil, 16) )/255.0,
                alpha: CGFloat( alpha )
        )
    }
}
```

**Testing**

```
let greenColorHEX = "00ff00"
let greenColor = UIColor(htmlColor: greenColorHEX, alpha: 1)

let a:CGFloat = 1
let b:CGFloat = 1
let c:CGFloat = 0
let d:CGFloat = 1

let yellowColor = UIColor(red: a, green: b, blue: c, alpha: d)
```