# Change UI color globally(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to do something like this:
In Setting of app, can chose a color, after that some UI element like Navigationbar, tabbar highlight will change to that color.

Is there anyway of tut for that?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I can do this by set navigation bar color in each view, but what I want is call one func somewhere in app and it change all

Comment: You can get an idea from link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217748/uicolor-code-in-a-variable-in-swift

Comment: Well? What happened? Did you figure it out?

Comment: Not yet. My problem is I can not tell the element change color

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd do it in Objective-C.

```
- (void)setCustomizedNavigationBarStyle {


    // UIBarButtonItem styling
    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc]init];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSDictionary *enabledTextAttributeDictionary = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor darkGrayColor], NSShadowAttributeName: shadow, NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:17.0]};

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class]]] setTitleTextAttributes:enabledTextAttributeDictionary forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSDictionary *disabledTextAttributeDictionary = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor], NSShadowAttributeName: shadow, NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:17.0]};

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class]]] setTitleTextAttributes:disabledTextAttributeDictionary forState:UIControlStateDisabled];



    // UINavigationBarTitle styling
    NSDictionary *titleAttributeDictionary = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor], NSShadowAttributeName: shadow, NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:18.0]};

    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationController class]]]setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributeDictionary];

}
```

You could call this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Once you translate to Swift, you'd add this line to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
setCustomizedNavigationBarStyle()
```

This should be readily translatable into Swift.

Adding to this, you can create a custom palette of colors. You may find this post on the topic helpful:

[How do I create a category in Xcode 6 or higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324021/how-do-i-create-a-category-in-xcode-6/31676701#31676701)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the color in `NSUserDefaults` and retrieve it by the key whenever you need to set that color to your view elements. You'll need an extension to `NSUserDefaults` that returns an UIColor.

Check out the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275662/saving-uicolor-to-and-loading-from-nsuserdefaults).

Hope it helps!